# VHDL - Arbitrarily Unconnected components

Tags: vhdl

Using Lattice Diamond 3.6.0.83.4
MachX03 starter kit

After a lot of struggling I figured out why many of my inputs were unconnected. It came down to some bad assignments in a debouncer module.

After I cleaned up the debouncer, everything worked fine, except for a handful of inputs. For some reason, these inputs refuse to connect to anything. I can't find much in the code because it's a lot of copy-pasting all over the place. I've exhaustively reviewed what I've done so it makes no sense to me why most of the code works, and 7 odd inputs refuse to connect.

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.numeric_bit.all;
    USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

    Entity hostlogic IS
        PORT(CLK : IN STD_LOGIC; 
            RESET : IN STD_LOGIC; 
            STOP : IN STD_LOGIC; 
            EMGC : IN STD_LOGIC; 
            READY : IN STD_LOGIC; 
            XENABLE : IN STD_LOGIC; 
            XSIN, XDIN, XHIN, XLIN,
            YSIN, YDIN, YHIN, YLIN,
            ZSIN, ZDIN, ZHIN, ZLIN,
            ASIN, ADIN, AHIN, ALIN,
            BSIN, BDIN, BHIN, BLIN,
            CSIN, CDIN, CHIN, CLIN,
            errIN : IN STD_LOGIC; 
            XSOUT, XDOUT, 
            YSOUT, YDOUT, 
            ZSOUT, ZDOUT,
            ASOUT, ADOUT, 
            BSOUT, BDOUT, 
            CSOUT, CDOUT, 
            errOUT: OUT STD_LOGIC;
            PERIPHERALSIN: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0); --FROM DEVICES TO SBC
            PERIPHERALSOUT: OUT STD_lOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0); --FROM DEVICES TO SBC DEBOUNCED
            PERIPH_DRIV_IN: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0); --FROM SBC TO DEVICE 
            PERIPH_DRIV_OUT: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0)
            ); --FROM SBC TO DEVICE DEBOUNCED
    END hostlogic;

    ARCHITECTURE hostproc OF hostlogic IS
    --SIGNAL LIST
    --INTERNAL DEBOUNCED, OVR ENABLES, LIMIT ENABLES, COPY OF INPUTS FOR WIRES
    signal ID_XS, ID_XD, XEN, XLIMS, ID_XLIN, ID_XHIN, I_XSIN, I_XDIN, I_XHIN, I_XLIN: std_logic;
    signal ID_YS, ID_YD, YEN, YLIMS, ID_YLIN, ID_YHIN, I_YSIN, I_YDIN, I_YHIN, I_YLIN: std_logic;
    signal ID_ZS, ID_ZD, ZEN, ZLIMS, ID_ZLIN, ID_ZHIN, I_ZSIN, I_ZDIN, I_ZHIN, I_ZLIN: std_logic;
    signal ID_AS, ID_AD, AEN, ALIMS, ID_ALIN, ID_AHIN, I_ASIN, I_ADIN, I_AHIN, I_ALIN: std_logic;
    signal ID_BS, ID_BD, BEN, BLIMS, ID_BLIN, ID_BHIN, I_BSIN, I_BDIN, I_BHIN, I_BLIN: std_logic;
    signal ID_CS, ID_CD, CEN, CLIMS, ID_CLIN, ID_CHIN, I_CSIN, I_CDIN, I_CHIN, I_CLIN: std_logic;
    SIGNAL I_RESET, I_STOP, I_EMGC, I_ERR, I_READY, ERR_MERGED, I_XENABLE: STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL ID_RESET, ID_STOP, ID_EMGC, ID_ERR, ID_READY, ID_XENABLE: STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL TESTER: STD_LOGIC;
    signal STATE: integer;
    SIGNAL IPERIPHERALS: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL IDRIVERS: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);

    --COMPONENT LIST
    COMPONENT stepper
        PORT(
            CLK : IN std_logic;
            OVR : IN std_logic;
            RESET: IN std_logic;
            AXIAL: IN std_logic;
            RADIAL: IN std_logic;
            ERR: IN std_logic;
            STOP: IN std_logic;
            HLIM: IN std_logic;
            stepin : IN std_logic;
            dirin : IN std_logic;
            dirout : OUT std_logic;
            stepout: OUT std_logic
            );
    END COMPONENT;

    COMPONENT DEBOUNCER
        PORT(
            CLK : IN std_logic;
            DIN : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 DOWNTO 0);
            DOUT: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 DOWNTO 0)
            );
    END COMPONENT;


    begin

    --LIMIT SWITCH ENABLES
    XLIMS <= '1' ; --if high, limit enabled. If low, limit disabled.
    YLIMS <= '1' ;
    ZLIMS <= '1' ;
    ALIMS <= '1' ;
    BLIMS <= '1' ;
    CLIMS <= '1' ;

    --COPY INPUTS TO INTERNAL WIRES
    --UNASSIGNED INPUTS WILL CAUSE ERROR IN SYSTEM
    I_READY <= READY;
    I_RESET <= RESET; 
    I_STOP <= STOP; 
    I_EMGC <= EMGC; 
    I_XENABLE <= XENABLE;
    I_ERR <= ERRIN;

    I_XSIN <= XSIN;
    I_XDIN <= XDIN;
    I_XHIN <= XHIN;
    I_XLIN <= XLIN;

    I_YSIN <= YSIN;
    I_YDIN <= YDIN;
    I_YHIN <= YHIN; 
    I_YLIN <= YLIN; 

    I_ZSIN <= ZSIN;
    I_ZDIN <= ZDIN;
    I_ZHIN <= ZHIN;
    I_ZLIN <= ZLIN;

    I_ASIN <= ASIN;
    I_ADIN <= ADIN;
    I_AHIN <= AHIN;
    I_ALIN <= ALIN;

    I_BSIN <= BSIN;
    I_BDIN <= BDIN;
    I_BHIN <= BHIN;
    I_BLIN <= BLIN;

    I_CSIN <= CSIN;
    I_CDIN <= CDIN;
    I_CHIN <= CHIN;
    I_CLIN <= CLIN;

    --SIGNAL OVERRIDE ENABLE SETTINGS
    XEN <= '0'; --should be low to prevent damage to tool 
    YEN <= '0'; --should be low to prevent damage to tool 
    ZEN <= '1'; --should be high to move tool away from working surface
    AEN <= '0'; --should be high for lave, low for plane, default is low
    BEN <= '0'; --should be high for lave, low for plane, default is low
    CEN <= '0'; --should be high for lave, low for plane, default is low

    --COMPONENT INSTANTIATION
    --STEPPERS

    --XAXIS
    XAXIS : stepper
        PORT MAP(
            CLK => CLK,
            OVR => XEN,
            RESET => RESET,
            AXIAL => '1',
            RADIAL => '0',
            ERR => ERR_MERGED,
            STOP => ID_STOP,
            HLIM => ID_XHIN,
            stepin => ID_XS,
            dirin => ID_XD,
            dirout => XDOUT,
            stepout => XSOUT
            );  


    --YAXIS
    YAXIS: stepper
        PORT MAP(
            CLK => CLK,
            OVR => YEN,
            RESET => RESET,
            AXIAL => '1',
            RADIAL => '0',
            ERR => ERR_MERGED,
            STOP => ID_STOP,
            HLIM => ID_YHIN,
            stepin => ID_YS,
            dirin => ID_YD,
            dirout => YDOUT,
            stepout => YSOUT
            );  
    --ZAXIS
    ZAXIS: stepper
        PORT MAP(
            CLK => CLK,
            OVR => ZEN,
            RESET => RESET,
            AXIAL => '1',
            RADIAL => '0',
            ERR => ERR_MERGED,
            STOP => ID_STOP,
            HLIM => ID_ZHIN,
            stepin => ID_ZS,
            dirin => ID_ZD,
            dirout => ZDOUT,
            stepout => ZSOUT
            );  

    --AAXIS
    AAXIS: stepper
        PORT MAP(
            CLK => CLK,
            OVR => AEN,
            RESET => RESET,
            AXIAL => '1',
            RADIAL => '0',
            ERR => ERR_MERGED,
            STOP => ID_STOP,
            HLIM => ID_AHIN,
            stepin => ID_AS,
            dirin => ID_AD,
            dirout => ADOUT,
            stepout => ASOUT
            );  

    --BAXIS
    BAXIS: stepper
        PORT MAP(
            CLK => CLK,
            OVR => BEN,
            RESET => RESET,
            AXIAL => '1',
            RADIAL => '0',
            ERR => ERR_MERGED,
            STOP => ID_STOP,
            HLIM => ID_BHIN,
            stepin => ID_BS,
            dirin => ID_BD,
            dirout => BDOUT,
            stepout => BSOUT
            );  

    --CAXIS
    CAXIS: stepper
        PORT MAP(
            CLK => CLK,
            OVR => CEN,
            RESET => RESET,
            AXIAL => '1',
            RADIAL => '0',
            ERR => ERR_MERGED,
            STOP => ID_STOP,
            HLIM => ID_CHIN,
            stepin => ID_CS,
            dirin => ID_CD,
            dirout => CDOUT,
            stepout => CSOUT
            );  





    statemachine: process(CLK)
        begin
        case STATE is

            --RESET/READY STATE
            when 0 =>                   --RESET/READY STATE
                if ID_RESET = '1' then      --RESET MUST STAY HIGH UNTIL MACHINE HAS FOUND ITS POSITION
                    STATE <= 0;         --IF RESET HIGH, STAY IN RESET
                elsif ID_RESET = '0' then   
                    STATE <= 1;         --IF RESET LOW, GO TO NORMAL OPERATION
                end if;

        --NORMAL OPERATION
        when 1 =>                   --NORMAL OPERATION
            if ID_STOP = '0' then   --IF ERROR THEN GO TO STOP STATE
                STATE <= 2;
            elsif ID_RESET <= '1' then --SINGAL FROME SBC, TRUE IS TRUE FALSE IS FALSE
                STATE <= 0;         --IF RESET SIGNAL GO TO RESET STATE
            end if;

        --STOP PROCEDURE
        when 2 =>                   --STOP PROCEDURE 
            if ID_RESET = '1' then      --SIGNAL FROM SBC, TRUE IS TRUE, FALSE IS FALSE
                STATE <= 0;         --IF RESET HIGH, GO TO RESET AND IGNORE STOP
            end if;

        --CATCHALL STATE
        when others =>              --CATCHALL REBOOT STATE
            if ID_RESET = '1' then
                STATE <= 0;
            end if;
    end case;
end process;


--DEBOUNCERS
--LIMITS
LIMITERS: DEBOUNCER
    PORT MAP(
        CLK => CLK,
        DIN(0) => I_XHIN,       --limit
        DIN(1) => I_XLIN,       --limit
        DIN(2) => I_YHIN,       --limit
        DIN(3) => I_YLIN,       --limit
        DIN(4) => I_ZHIN,       --limit
        DIN(5) => I_ZLIN,       --limit
        DIN(6) => I_AHIN,       --limit
        DIN(7) => I_ALIN,       --limit
        DIN(8) => I_BHIN,       --limit
        DIN(9) => I_BLIN,       --limit
        DIN(10) => I_CHIN,      --limit
        DIN(11) => I_CLIN,      --limit
        DIN(12) => I_XDIN,      --STEPPER DIRECTIOON
        DIN(13) => I_YDIN,      --STEPPER DIRECTIOON
        DIN(14) => I_ZDIN,      --STEPPER DIRECTIOON
        DIN(15) => open,
        DOUT(0) => ID_XHIN,     --limit, internal
        DOUT(1) => ID_XLIN,     --limit, internal
        DOUT(2) => ID_YHIN,     --limit, internal
        DOUT(3) => ID_YLIN,     --limit, internal
        DOUT(4) => ID_ZHIN,     --limit, internal
        DOUT(5) => ID_ZLIN,     --limit, internal
        DOUT(6) => ID_AHIN,     --limit, internal
        DOUT(7) => ID_ALIN,     --limit, internal
        DOUT(8) => ID_BHIN,     --limit, internal
        DOUT(9) => ID_BLIN,     --limit, internal
        DOUT(10) => ID_CHIN,        --limit, internal
        DOUT(11) => ID_CLIN,        --limit, internal
        DOUT(12) => ID_XD,      --STEPPER DIRECTIOON, internal
        DOUT(13) => ID_YD,      --STEPPER DIRECTIOON, internal
        DOUT(14) => ID_ZD,      --STEPPER DIRECTIOON, internal
        DOUT(15) => OPEN);

--DEBOUNCERS
--LIMITS
CONTROLS: DEBOUNCER
    PORT MAP(
        CLK => CLK,
        DIN(0) => I_RESET,  --From SBC
        DIN(1) => I_STOP,       --From SBC
        DIN(2) => I_EMGC,       --From Pushbutton
        DIN(3) => I_READY,  --From SBC
        DIN(4) => I_XENABLE,    --from SBC
        DIN(5) => I_ERR,    --from Peripherals
        DIN(6) => I_XSIN,       --STEPPER STEP INSTRUCTION
        DIN(7) => I_YSIN,       --STEPPER STEP INSTRUCTION
        DIN(8) => I_ZSIN,       --STEPPER STEP INSTRUCTION
        DIN(9) => I_ASIN,       --STEPPER STEP INSTRUCTION
        DIN(10) => I_BSIN,      --STEPPER STEP INSTRUCTION
        DIN(11) => I_CSIN,      --STEPPER STEP INSTRUCTION
        DIN(12) => I_ADIN,      --STEPPER DIRECTION
        DIN(13) => I_BDIN,      --STEPPER DIRECTION
        DIN(14) => I_CDIN,      --STEPPER DIRECTION
        DIN(15) => OPEN,
        DOUT(0) => ID_RESET,    --internal reset signal
        DOUT(1) => ID_STOP, --internal stop signal
        DOUT(2) => ID_EMGC, --internal emergency signal
        DOUT(3) => ID_READY,    --internal ready signal
        DOUT(4) => ID_XENABLE,--internal signal
        DOUT(5) => ID_ERR,  --internal signal
        DOUT(6) => ID_XS,   --stepper step instruction, internal
        DOUT(7) => ID_YS,   --stepper step instruction, internal
        DOUT(8) => ID_ZS,   --stepper step instruction, internal
        DOUT(9) => ID_AS,   --stepper step instruction, internal
        DOUT(10) => ID_BS,  --stepper step instruction, internal
        DOUT(11) => ID_CS,  --stepper step instruction, internal
        DOUT(12) => ID_AD,      --STEPPER DIRECTIOON, internal
        DOUT(13) => ID_BD,      --STEPPER DIRECTIOON, internal
        DOUT(14) => ID_CD,      --STEPPER DIRECTIOON, internal
        DOUT(15) => OPEN);


--DEBOUNCERS
--PERIPHERAL END
PERIPH_IO: DEBOUNCER
    PORT MAP(
        CLK => CLK,
        DIN => PERIPHERALSIN,
        DOUT => IPERIPHERALS);

--DEBOUNCERS
--SBC END
PERIPH_DRIVER: DEBOUNCER
    PORT MAP(
        CLK => CLK,
        DIN => PERIPH_DRIV_IN,
        DOUT => IDRIVERS);

--INTERNAL SIGNALS TO OUTPUTS
PERIPHERALSOUT <= IPERIPHERALS;
PERIPH_DRIV_OUT <= IDRIVERS;
ERROUT <= ID_ERR;

--LIMIT ENABLER


--ERROR LOGIC
ERROR_LOGIC: PROCESS(CLK)
    BEGIN
    IF ID_RESET = '0' THEN
        IF (ID_EMGC = '1' OR ID_STOP = '1') AND ID_RESET = '0' THEN             --CHECK STOP TRIGGERS 
            ERR_MERGED <= '1' ;
        ELSIF XEN = '0' AND ERR_MERGED = '0' THEN   --CHECK X LIMITS IF NO OVERRIDE
            IF ID_XHIN = '0' THEN
                ERR_MERGED <= XLIMS;                --PASS ERROR ON AXIS LIMITER CONDITION
            ELSIF ID_XLIN = '0' THEN
                ERR_MERGED <= XLIMS ;
            END IF;
        ELSIF YEN = '0' AND ERR_MERGED = '0'  THEN  --CHECK Y LIMITS IF NO OVERRIDE 
            IF ID_YHIN = '0' THEN
                ERR_MERGED <= YLIMS ;
            ELSIF ID_YLIN = '0' THEN                    --PASS ERROR ON AXIS LIMITER CONDITION
                ERR_MERGED <= YLIMS ;
            END IF;
        ELSIF ZEN = '0' AND ERR_MERGED = '0'  THEN  --CHECK Z LIMITS IF NO OVERRIDE
            IF ID_ZHIN = '0' THEN 
                ERR_MERGED <= ZLIMS ;
            ELSIF ID_ZLIN = '0' THEN                    --PASS ERROR ON AXIS LIMITER CONDITION
                ERR_MERGED <= ZLIMS ;
            END IF;
        ELSIF AEN = '0' AND ERR_MERGED = '0'  THEN  --CHECK A LIMITS IF NO OVERRIDE
            IF ID_AHIN = '0' THEN
                ERR_MERGED <= ALIMS ;
            ELSIF ID_ALIN = '0' THEN                    --PASS ERROR ON AXIS LIMITER CONDITION
                ERR_MERGED <= ALIMS ;
            END IF;
        ELSIF BEN = '0' AND ERR_MERGED = '0'  THEN  --CHECK B LIMITS IF NO OVERRIDE
            IF ID_BHIN = '0' THEN
                ERR_MERGED <= BLIMS ;
            ELSIF ID_BLIN = '0' THEN                    --PASS ERROR ON AXIS LIMITER CONDITION
                ERR_MERGED <= BLIMS ;
            END IF;
        ELSIF CEN = '0' AND ERR_MERGED = '0'  THEN  --CHECK C LIMITS IF NO OVERRIDE
            IF ID_CHIN = '0' THEN
                ERR_MERGED <= CLIMS ; 
            ELSIF ID_CLIN = '0' THEN                    --PASS ERROR ON AXIS LIMITER CONDITION
                ERR_MERGED <= CLIMS ; 
            END IF;
        END IF;
    ELSIF ID_RESET = '1' THEN
        ERR_MERGED <= '0'; 
    END IF;
    IF READY ='1' AND XENABLE = '1' THEN
        TESTER <= '1';
    ELSE
        TESTER <= '0';
    END IF;
END PROCESS;




end hostproc;
```

Once I try to assign pins, only the following ports remain unconnected:

READY, XENABLE, YHIN, YLIN, ZLIN, BHIN, BLIN.

There are two debouncer instances, so if the signals were going screwy in the same places, that'd explain it. However this is not the case as the signals appear to be disconnecting somewhere else. I'm completely at wits end on what to do. I've caught myself trying the same solutions again without luck, so it's time for me to step back for a bit before I resort to tearing my hair out.

Comment: It's illegal in VHDL to leave an input port open unless that input port has a default value. If you only need to connect 14 of the 15 bits, why not connect it to (eg) `'0'`, ie: `DIN(15) => '0',`

Comment: Whether `DIN(15) => open` is legal or not is tool-dependent.

Comment: Making the change to `DIN(15) => '0'` means this compiles fine. So, what is your problem? What do you mean by "unconnected"? What do you mean by "only the following ports remain unconnected: READY, XENABLE, YHIN, YLIN, ZLIN, BHIN, BLIN."

Comment: (1) Your clocked processes are faulty; they require `if rising_edge(clk) then ... end if;` around their logic. (2) As you have some hard-wired internal enables `XEN` etc, these may lead the synth tool to trim away "unused" logic, which may leave some un-connected inputs. (3) The chances of getting something this complex to work, without getting it right in simulation first, are pretty small.

Comment: Brian's comment answers my question: it seems like you're trying to synthesise this before even simulating. Doing that is doing things the hard way; always simulate first: it is easier to debug and quicker to fix the bugs.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.3 Port clauses "If a formal port is associated with an actual port, signal, or expression, then the formal port is said to be *connected*. If a formal port is instead associated with the reserved word open, then the formal is said to be *unconnected*. It is an error if a port of mode **in** is unconnected (see 6.5.6.3) or unassociated (see 6.5.7.3) unless its declaration includes a default expression (see 6.5.2)."  There's no guarantee witthout validating that Lattice Diamond is making a distinction between unconnected and unassociated (with a pin, during synthesis).

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.7 Association lists, 6.5.7.1, paragraph 18 "It is an error if an actual of **open** is associated with a formal interface object that is associated individually. An actual of **open** counts as the single association allowed for the corresponding formal interface object, but does not supply a constant, signal, or variable (as is appropriate to the object class of the formal) to the formal."  (Your debouncer instantiations limiters and controls, din(15), and about here is where the question of validity comes in, show actual error messages).

Comment: @ Matthew Taylor. The issue is not the ports that are intentionally left open (yeah, this is a problem too, fixed that), the issue is the inputs that are passing through the debouncer bank. Those signals i listed at the end are crapping out and coming up as unconnected. Maybe Brian Drummond has the right idea about the problem. That still doesn't explain, though, why some would work and others might crap out.

Comment: Interesting. After changing the ZEN to 0, i no longer had any problems with YHIN and YLIN inputs, but I had a new problem with ZHIN.

Comment: @BrianDrummond was right. It's the bloody hard-coded controls. The instant I replaced them with inputs all of the problems went away. Other inputs apparently didn't have anything to do in the body of the code, so once I gave them something to do, they also stopped being stripped out.

Is there a way of getting around this? The FPGA does have some switches, but I'd like to avoid having to use those to control device behavior. I was really hoping to just be able to flip one or two bits to get different behavior out of this.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor : what is legal VHDL is never tool-dependent.Admittedly, the tools don't always know that... And in particular there's no expectation that a synth tool accepts all legal VHDL.

Comment: @T_Poda : You have to wire your controls to something other than a constant , or it's like enclosing an entire C program in `if (0) { ... }`. If this interfaces to a MCU, put them all in an MCU-writable register. If it's on an eval board, bring them out to pins you aren't using, and use jumper wires to set them `'1'` or `'0'`. Or something. Maybe a register connected to a UART or I2C slave. You need some external way of controlling them or they might as well not be controls.

Comment: @BrianDrummond You're right. I don't mean "legal", I mean "acceptable". There are some things that are tool-dependent, eg `OP_PORT => (others => '0'),` in a port map will analyse on one tool but not on another. Ditto explicitly declaring an output of a task as a variable in the package body, but assuming the default in the package.